# Using IMPORTXML in Google Sheets: How to Combine XML Data Sources as a Single Set Before Applying XPATH Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importxml

Using the `IMPORTXML` function on Google Sheets, I've got two XML data sets at two URLs, respectively in cells `A1` and `A2`.  I've got the XPATH query in cell `H1`.  I would like to run a single query on the *combined* XML datasets (i.e., the combined result of XML data from URLs in `A1` and `A2`.

As an example, [this URL][1] is in cell `A1` and [this second URL][2] is in cell `A2`.  The xpath in cell `H1` is `(//*[local-name() = 'NEW_DATE'])[last() - position() = 25]/../*[local-name()! = 'Id']`.

I've tried the below formula, which returns two query results, one for each URL where the XML query in cell `H1` contains `[last() - position() = 11]` or `#N/A` error for the first URL and the 25th row for the second URL where the XML query is as above, i.e., `[last() - position() = 25]`:

> =QUERY({IMPORTXML(A1,H1);IMPORTXML(A2,H1)})

Note that in this sample, the first URL has 13 results as of the date of this question (hence retreiving row 11 when the XML query includes `[last() - position() = 11]` works but not when the XML query includes `[last() - position() = 25]` because there is no 25th row in that URL's XML data).  **Combining XML results of the first and second URLs, I would like to retrieve the 12th row in the second URL, which would be the 25th row if both URLs are combined.**

[This user's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593019/use-importxml-to-import-from-multiple-urls-at-one-time) is similar though the OP seems to run a common XPATH query on multiple, *uncombined* URL sources.

I would like to run a single query *after* the URLs are combined into a single dataset.

Is this feasible?

[1]: http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=year(NEW_DATE) eq 2022
[2]: http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=year(NEW_DATE) eq 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the xml data by using an array

- Enter this formula in Cell A4
  `={IMPORTXML($B$1,$B$2);IMPORTXML($D$1,$D$2)}`
- Then transpose every 14th set of rows using this formula
  `=ArrayFormula(split(transpose(split(regexreplace(query(array_constrain(if(mod(row(A4:A), 14) = 4, "^", "|") & A4:A,max(row(A4:A) * (A4:A <> "")),1),,9^99), "^\^",), "^", true, false)), "|", true, false))`

*How to adapt the formula to your data*

The formula (as written) assumes that the `IMPORTXML` data commences on row#4 but this may not be true in every case.

In order to adapt the formula to the location of your data, the key element is:

- `if(mod(row(A4:A), 14) = 4,` In this case, the mod of the first row of data (row#4) divided by 14 (the number of rows in each set of data) = 4.

To adapt the formula:

- identify the row number for the first row of `IMPORTXML` data array
- calculate the `MOD` where the dividend = the starting row#, and the divisor = 14
- substitute your calculated mod for '4' in the `if` statement.

---

Your screen should look something like this. This snapshot is cropped; the data for each day extends across to column P
[image]

Hat-tip:  Ed on Google Support: [Transpose from column to rows, every nth rows](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/56794556/transpose-from-column-to-rows-every-nth-rows?hl=en)

Comment: The formulas worked with a new sheet but when I transferred them to an existing sheet and made adjustments for cell and range references, it didn't work any longer.  I think it may have to do with the second formula's ```ARRAY_CONSTRAIN``` function and / OR functions nested inside it, such as ```MOD```.  Can you share your sheet or explain what's happening in the above functions?  Thanks.

Comment: The key is `MOD`. I can't explain why your formula would work with a new sheet but not with the original sheet (assuming you are using the **exact same data set**) . Anyway, I just added an explanation of how to adapt the formula to your data.